# Increasing the Transaction Scope timeout limit dynamically and for one method only

Tags: c#

I have a .NET core API project and I just want to increase the transaction scope timeout for the one method which is performing a bulk insert then set it back to its default setting.

I added the code in the web config where you can update the timeout limit which worked, but that sets it for the whole project which is not what I want to do.

Is this possible and if so how?

```
public List<TEntity> AddRange(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        int takeCount = 999;

        int counter = (entities.Count % takeCount) == 0
            ? (entities.Count / takeCount)
            : (entities.Count / takeCount) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                List<TEntity> subList = entities.Skip(i * takeCount).Take(takeCount).ToList();

                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

                context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(subList);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }
```

The error that is thrown is thrown on the save changes but it's only thrown on my localhost and not on the server.

InvalidOperationException: The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend to use `SqlBulkCopy` for a very large amount of data (more than 1 million rows).

As a second choice, if you are using Entity Framework Core, try to pass the entire collection to the `context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange` function and check performance.

After trying the above two options, you could try handle the transaction by yourself:

```
public List<TEntity> AddRange(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        int takeCount = 999;

        int counter = (entities.Count % takeCount) == 0
            ? (entities.Count / takeCount)
            : (entities.Count / takeCount) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            //Take control over the transaction by yourself
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                List<TEntity> subList = entities.Skip(i * takeCount).Take(takeCount).ToList();

                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

                context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(subList);
                context.SaveChanges();
                //Commit the transaction before continue with the next page
                transaction.Commit();  
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }
```

**Note:** This should solve your exception, but I'm not sure about performance.

Comment: I added some more information and I'm not entirely sure how to add that. This exception is also only thrown on the local host and not the server. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: If you are going to make a Bulk Insert then is recommended `SqlBulkCopy` than DbContext. 
Have you tried to pass the complete list to the `.AddRange(entities);`? EF Core should be smart enough to handle the entire collection.

Comment: Yes, I have passed the entire list to the .AddRange(entities) but it gives me that exception that I mentioned above. The thing is though it works fine if we publish the code to the server on the local system, it throws that error and the only reason I can think that happens is that the local is slower than the server. Is this an issue? To give you an idea it's trying to save 14500 records that's why we have the paginated kind of save happening.

Comment: @ID10T_E330r Local always be slower than a server, but you can't trust on that. Have you tried handle the commit by yourself, as I explain in the new posted solution?

Comment: I've been trying to find some way to implement the SqlBulkCopy code and I'm not sure how to insert the data. Could you please give me an example of how to implement this?

Comment: I managed to get the SqlBulkCopy to work but it doesn't work for DbGeography fields, do you know a workaround by any chance?

Comment: @ID10T_E330r Could you show what errors thorw?

Comment: "The given value of type DbGeography from the data source cannot be converted to type udt of the specified target column." This is the error that is thrown.

Comment: So I added some mappings but now the inner exception is, "Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089."

Comment: I recommend using the FluentApi configuration approach on Entity Framework, because you have more control over the mapped entities. This exception is because you are defining a field type with a unknown type

Comment: I Managed to come right with this error. All I did was convert the DbGeography type to a SqlGeography type and the issue was solved. Thanks for the help though